# PyQt, checkbox в QMenuBar активация меню "Поверх всех окон"

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt6, qmenubar, windowflags

Необходимо чтобы в `QMenuBar` проставлялся `chekBox` и приложение работало в режиме "Поверх всех окон", те на закреплялось на самом верху и всегда было видимым.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если в добавляю в код:

```
self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.WindowType.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
```

Данная функция работает, но приложение всегда остается в режиме "Поверх всех окон". Для пользователя должен быть выбор.

Что я предпринял, написал метод, в нем я и думаю кроется вся сложность, его код:

```
def top_of_all_windows(self):
    if self.ui.action.setCheckable(True):
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.WindowType.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
```

И подключил его к триггеру:

```
self.ui.action.triggered.connect(self.top_of_all_windows)
```

При установки "галочки" в `chekBox`, ничего не происходит. 
Где кроется моя ошибка?

Пример кода:

```
from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from test_c_ui import Ui_MainWindow


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.ui.action.triggered.connect(self.top_of_all_windows)
        self.show()

    def top_of_all_windows(self):
        if self.ui.action.setCheckable(True):
            self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.WindowType.WindowStaysOnTopHint)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

---

**Update**

Код оформления:

```
from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(265, 297)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(parent=MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(parent=MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 265, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menu = QtWidgets.QMenu(parent=self.menubar)
        self.menu.setObjectName("menu")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(parent=MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.action = QtGui.QAction(parent=MainWindow)
        self.action.setCheckable(True)
        self.action.setObjectName("action")
        self.menu.addAction(self.action)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menu.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.menu.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Меню"))
        self.action.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Поверх всех окон"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Что именно должно происходить - пользователь ставить галочку в `chekBox` в `menuBar` у пункта *"Поверх всех окон"* и программа работает всегда поверх всех окон. 
Если пользователь снимает галочку и нажимает на рабочий стол или другое окно, текущее окно не теряет фокус и не переходит на второй план.

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему и лучше расскажите что вы хотите сделать.

Comment: Добавил пример и полное описание.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> enum [**Qt::WindowType**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qt.html#WindowType-enum)
> flags [**Qt::WindowFlags**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qt.html#WindowType-enum)
>
> Этот тип перечисления используется для указания различных свойств оконной системы виджета.
> ...

Попробуйте так:

```
'''
from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets                               # PyQt6
'''
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets                               # PyQt5


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(265, 297)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(parent=MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(parent=MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 265, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menu = QtWidgets.QMenu(parent=self.menubar)
        self.menu.setObjectName("menu")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(parent=MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        
#        self.action = QtGui.QAction(parent=MainWindow)                  # PyQt6
        self.action = QtWidgets.QAction(parent=MainWindow)               # PyQt5
        self.action.setCheckable(True)
        self.action.setObjectName("action")
        self.menu.addAction(self.action)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menu.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.menu.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Меню"))
        self.action.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Поверх всех окон"))


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.action.triggered.connect(self.top_of_all_windows)

# -----------------------------> vvvvvvv <-------------------------------------        
    def top_of_all_windows(self, checked):
        print(f'checked = {checked}') 
#        if self.action.setCheckable(True):
        if checked:
            flag = self.windowFlags() | \
                QtCore.Qt.WindowType.WindowStaysOnTopHint | \
                QtCore.Qt.WindowType.X11BypassWindowManagerHint
        else:
            flag = self.windowFlags() & ~QtCore.Qt.WindowType.WindowStaysOnTopHint
# ----------------------------------> ^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ <---            
        self.setWindowFlags(flag)
        self.show()                                                      # <---- !!!


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]